# What is an infinite language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I just started reading about formal language theory and what i have learnt so far that:

**Alphabet** is a finite set of symbols.

**String/Word:** is always finite.

Because a language is set of strings of symbols and per definition alphabet and strings both are finite then how can a language be infinite?

I searched a lot but did not find any explaination so i am asking this question here, any help would be great for me.

Comment: Every integer is finite but there is an infinite number of integers.

Comment: In addition to ricis comment: Imagine the language over the alphabet $\{1\}$, that contains every finite string of $1$s (namely the language $\{1\}^\ast = \{\varepsilon, 1, 11, 111, \ldots\} = L$. Every string in $L$ represents the unary representation of a natural number $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$. So there is clearly a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $L$, namely $f: n \mapsto 1^n$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, so is $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every individual string is finite, but there are infinitely many different ones. For example, $0$, $00$, $000$, $0000$, ... .